# phpQuery error handling

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm using phpQuery to scrape some information from a page based on user input, but I'm trying to set up error handling if the user enters in something that doesn't exist.

For example, the user enters an incorrect product number it may result in

```
Warning: file_get_contents([function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in
```

What can I use in an if statement to check for a phpQuery error in an instance like this?

For example

```
if(...error...){
    echo json_encode("error" => 'Incorrect value entered');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the logic you plan on using with the input in a try-catch block.

Something like:

```
try {
  <..insert your logic here..>
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo json_encode("error" => "Incorrect value entered");
}
```